# How to I add simulator for iphone 4/5 in Xcode 6.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I am not sure if i am doing it right. Please help.

To add simulator,  goto > windows > devices

problem:

1) When I tried to add simulator for iphone 5 or 4 , it show iOS version 8.3

the dialogbox show :

```
Simulator name : iphone 4s
Device Type   : iphone 4s
iOS version    : iOS8.3
```

Is this correct? iphone 4s should be using ios lower than ios 8 right?

How to I do testing for iphone 4/5 using simulator ?

Comment: You need to go to Devices-> Simulators-> Add sinulators I guess

Comment: The 4s supports iOS 8. That seems correct to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode 6 only supports iOS 7 and iOS8. You could use iOS 7 for iPhone 4s or iPhone 5, just install the iOS 7.1 simulator from

> Xcode > Preferences > Downloads.

iPhone 5 and iPhone 4S can be updated to run iOS 8, so it is perfectly ok to test iOS 8 with these phones.

Answer (score 7):

In the Xcode menu, go to **Windows > Devices**, and at the bottom left click on the `+` button.

[image: screenshot showing the location of the + button]

[image: screenshot showing the create a new simulator dialog]

Answer (score 1):

> Is this correct? iphone 4s should be using ios lower than ios 8 right?

It is correct. I have an actual iPhone 4s and it is running iOS 8.3. (In fact, it is my primary development testing device for iOS 8.)

You can install earlier simulators, but there is nothing wrong with what you're seeing.

(And yes, this means that in order to develop for iOS 8, you need to support screen sizes ranging from the tiny iPhone 4s to the massive iPhone 6 Plus. Good luck.)