# Xcode configuration bar how to switch to iPhone 6 or other device

Tags: ios, xcode, configuration

Can anyone tell me how to view as iPhone6 or other device in Xcode configuration bar? Now I can only see iPhone7, iPhone SE and 4s.

Actually I can run it by using iPhone 6 or any other device simulator, just don't know how to choose view as iPhone 6 when I do the UI staff. All choices I can see at the bottom are iPhone 7/7s, iPhone SE and iPhone 4s

Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuZ7A.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to I add simulator for iphone 4/5 in Xcode 6.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547474/how-to-i-add-simulator-for-iphone-4-5-in-xcode-6-3-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to add a iPhone 6-sized ViewController in your storyboard. iPhone 7, SE & 4S represent the various size classes of iPhone. Since iPhone 7 is the same size as the 6, use the iPhone 7's ViewController -- the layout will persist on your iPhone 6 device.

Comment: It makes sense. Does that mean there is no possibility that I can choose "view as iPhone 6" at the bottom of configuration bar by using the latest version of Xcode?

Comment: Yep, stick with iPhone 7. Again, these are just for sizing.

Answer (score 0):

You must run the following command:

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6"
```

More infos here: [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-simulator-ios)